# 400 Bad Request Error when trying to load JSON output on full calendar

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

The console logs the string(i.e title) and at the Network tab shows that the string was posted. But I can't seem to get the calendar to display it on the screen even though I am using `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json);` to get back the events from the json source on success.

Any inputs on how to check this or how to get the events to display would be appreciated.

Json response when a console.log is done on it : `Salah[{"id":"24","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-02 10:00:00","end":"2016-06-02 14:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":null},{"id":"26","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-23 08:30:00","end":"2016-06-23 11:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":"green"}]`

The above error is logged into the console and it prevents these events from bring displayed on the calendar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the JSON object name you should used the unnamed object instead of using the object `Salah`. In back-end API please return the info with out the array key in the format as stated below.

```
[{"id":"24","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-02 10:00:00","end":"2016-06-02 14:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":null},
 {"id":"26","title":"Salah","start":"2016-06-23 08:30:00","end":"2016-06-23 11:30:00","url":null,"allDay":false,"color":"green"}]
```

Or you may change the format like `response.Salah` on front-end.

Comment: Can you point me out in the right direction by advising me how that can be achieved(i.e returning without the array key) ?